# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SIGameScene setDelegate:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please help ! 
i have got this error , the app run on simulator and on device ... 
what is the reason ?

SIgameScene.h code :

```
@interface SIGameScene : SKScene {
    BOOL gameRunning;
    double gameStartedAt;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int lifes;
    int level;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *background;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *spaceship;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *projectilesFriendly;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *projectilesEnemy;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *invaders;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SIGameSceneDelegate, SKSceneDelegate> delegate;

- (void)startGame;
- (void)pauseGame;
- (void)stopGame;
- (void)moveSpaceshipSidewaysByAngle:(double)angleInDegrees;

@end
```

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from how you use the interface not the definition of it. Can you post the code which is using it.

Comment: Hi , Which code you want to see please ?